# How can I add new elements to object of ArrayList that I took from newInstance() method?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List list1 = new ArrayList();
         list1.add(1);
         list1.add(2);
         list1.add(3);

        Class myClass = list1.getClass();
        Object list2 = myClass.newInstance(); //I want to create the same object like list1

        System.out.println(list1.getClass()); //result: class java.util.ArrayList
        System.out.println(list2.getClass()); //result: class java.util.ArrayList

}
}
```

How can I add some elements to list2 object,
like I did that with list1 object. FOR EXAMPLE: list2.add(4);

Comment: Why would you want to use `newInstance` there?

Comment: cast it and add it. Example -> ((List)list2).add(4)

Comment: Because I am studying java and I have such task. For example I didn't know the class of the object and I should create new object of unknown class. I just make my task simplier to ask the question

Comment: *If you want it to 'create the same object', why are you calling `newInstance()`?* Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You cast it to `List`:

```
List list2 = (List)myClass.newInstance();
```

...and then use it as normal.

To use specific methods, you need a reference that is of the type that has those methods. `List` has the various `List` methods, for instance. If you needed to use `ArrayList`-specific methods (like `ensureCapacity`), you'd need to use `ArrayList` instead of `List` above.

If you're not sure what class to use for the cast, but you have a reasonable set of classes it might be, you can use `list2 instanceof x` or even `list2.getClass() == x.getClass()` until you know, and then use that.

---

If you don't know what the object is, but do know the signature of a method you need to call on it, then you'd use reflection (`java.reflect`). For instance, we know that `add` accepts one parameter of type `Object`, so:

```
Object list2 = myClass.newInstance();
String methodName = "add";
Class[] paramTypes = {Object.class};
Method method = list2.getClass().getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
method.invoke(list2, new Object[] { 4 });
```

You have to know *something* about the object. I mean, you can ask it what methods it has (see the various methods of `Class`), and you can get their parameter types, but you can't call them meaningfully if you have no idea what they are.

Comment: But what if I don't know the class of my new object before the moment of compilation

Comment: If you know list of objects from which it can be, then check with instanceof in if-else cases and type cast and use the object.

Comment: @OFUSs: I've added a note about reflection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It was helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below ,

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(3);

   Class myClass = list1.getClass();
   Object list2 = myClass.newInstance(); //I want to create the same object like list1

   Method m = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("add", new Class[] {Object.class});
   m.invoke(list2, 4);

   for(int i : (List<Integer>)list2) {
       System.out.println(i);
   }
```